# Silverlight and Flex application automation using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: silverlight, apache-flex, selenium, webdriver

I am currently investigating how to automate silverlight and flex based applications using selenium webdriver. I read many blogs and many questions on Stack Overflow but still did not get the answer whether its possible or not.

If anyone has experience of automating such applications using webdriver, then please let me know the exact steps.

Why we are behind webdriver is the support for multiple browsers.

Comment: This is overly broad; and I'm not sure if it can be concretely answered.  First, what have you read?  What did they recommend?  What have you tried?  What were your results?  What did you expect that was different from the results?  Second, Silverlight and the Flash Player are different technologies; the approach used in one may not be the same as the other.  Perhaps this should be split up into two separate questions.

Comment: I will try to close this as Too Broad.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium may not support for all the controls of Silver light application, better use White Code plex to automate silver light.